# Signing our executable seems to makes any memory dump from a customer crash useless to us

Tags: c++, visual-studio, memory-dump

We've been getting memory dumps that are unusable, despite storing the pdb for those particular builds we cannot view the call stack. We have tested that our pdb files work do work, but they cease to work after the executable has been signed. Is there anyway of remedy this?

Comment: What is the specific failure you are getting?  A symbol mismatch?